# What is the way of getting an array of notes out of a midi file with music21?

Tags: python-3.x, music21

I'm currently trying to use music21. I've got a database of pieces for flutes that are midi file. Very few features.

I can create a Stream out of the midi (through

```html
midi.translate.midiFileToStream(path)
```

), but then how can I convert it into an array of notes, pitches or notes durations?